# Caching cloud file list

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cloud

I have more than a million of files located on a remote cloud file storage service, and I need to track as fast as I can whether a single file exists or not.

Since it takes a few minutes to build up a list of available of files, I need to cache a list but I'm not sure what's the optimal way to go here.

What would be the fastest and less resource expensive way to keep track of a list of files?

Comment: If you are not going to be doing more then just checking for existance why not use the filesystem to track the files and use a command like `find` to check for existance?

Comment: I am able to mount the cloud files, but ls or find are slower than the local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Most APIs allow you to call the file listing while giving a regular expression for the listing. I know the PHP sdk of AWS supports this on S3. I think that is a faster and more accurate way to do what you want to do.

Comment: i need to iterate through thousands of files and check whether they exists or not. using an api request for each one would take years